# Need help getting the title from a video using jQuery (YouTube API v3)

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

So, I've recently came across learning how to use the YouTube API v3, and I've personally learned a lot from this API of theirs - What I'm wanting to know is how do I fetch the title of the video so when a term is searched for, it will display the title of the video.

Here is my code: http://codepen.io/mistkaes/pen/MYqrXW

As always, thanks for helping out!

```
    function openIt(videoId) {
 ideVideo = videoId,
 container = "#abrePlayer";
 //open a lightbox, or do something else with the video id. In this case, let's create an iframe to play the little bastard.
 iframe = '<iframe width="600" height="400" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+ideVideo+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  $(container).html(iframe)
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  //find using typed word
  $('#searchIt').keyup(function() {
    var itemsPerPage = 20;
    var term = $(this).val();
    var searchUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+term+'&format=5&max-results='+itemsPerPage+'&v=2&alt=jsonc';

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: searchUrl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(res) {
     $("#resultadosGerais").html('');
        console.log();

        if(res.data.items){
          //if there are items in our response
          var item = res.data.items;

          $.each(item, function(i, data) {
            var videoId = data.id;
            var thumb = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + videoId + "/default.jpg";

            var showThis = '<div id=\"result\" onClick=\"openIt(\''+ videoId + '\');"> <img src=\"' + thumb + '\" /><p id=\"media-header\">'+videoId+'</p></div><br />';
            $("#resultadosGerais").append(showThis);
          });
        } else {
          $("#resultadosGerais").append('No Results Found');
        }
      }})
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may easily analyse the response you're getting from the youtube API by using a example URL, i.e http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Beethoven&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc

This returns a JSON array, which you'er displaying in your previews. I believe you're trying to display the title there instead of the ID?

```
var showThis = '<div id=\"result\" onClick=\"openIt(\''+ videoId + '\');"> <img src=\"' + thumb + '\" /><p id=\"media-header\">'+data.title+'</p></div><br />';
        $("#resultadosGerais").append(showThis);
```

the key here is `data.title` which contains the title of the video